# geting geograpic locations from an address list

Tags: qgis, python, openstreetmap, address

I have a table with 150 addresses. I would like to automaticly generate a point shapefile/PostGIS layer from all of them. Is that possible in any way or do I have to search for every single address to find its geographic location?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936794/geocoding-a-list-of-addresses-from-a-csv-file) may be a solution.

Comment: Only for programmers

Comment: @warrieka He did use the python tag

Comment: oh yes, sorry did not see that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In qgis you can use the [mmqgis](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mmqgis/) plugin to geocode addresses.

How to use this plugin can be found here: http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis in the chapter **Geocode Tools**